# Using different functions for Windows 7 and Windows 10 in dll

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I created dynamic library(dll) which is using function `GetScaleFactorForMonitor` from windows API. However this function was introduced in Windows 8.1 and those dll won't load at Windows 7 obviously. I am thinking about the solution to have two versions of the same method in one dll and use it according to Windows version.

Does anyone have any suggestions. I would be up to keep `GetScaleFactorForMonitor` in my code.

Comment: If you use static linking, your app will most likely display an error message on Windows 7 because it won't be able to find that API and or dll. So you will most likely have to use dynamic linking for that API by detect OS version and then use `GetProcAdddress` to fetch the address of that API.

Comment: @Asesh or using your linker's delay-load feature, if it has one. That will wrap the GetProcAddress() logic for you at runtime.

Comment: @ase Do not check for OS versions when discovering functionality. Just discover the functionality using whichever run-time dynamic linking scheme you chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need something like this:

```
typedef HRESULT CALLBACK GETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR(HMONITOR hMon, DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR* pScale);

...

HMODULE hm = LoadLibrary("Shcore.dll");     // GetScaleFactorForMonitor is here

GETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR* pGETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR = NULL;

if (hm)
{
  pGETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR = (GETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR*)GetProcAddress(hm, "GetScaleFactorForMonitor");
}

if (pGETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR)
{ 
  // GetScaleFactorForMonitor exists, call it like this:
  HRESULT hr = (*pGETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR)(whatever parameters);   // call GetScaleFactorForMonitor
  // instead of like this:
  // HRESULT hr = GetScaleFactorForMonitor(whatever parameters);
}
else
{
  // GetScaleFactorForMonitor not available
  ...
}
```

You probably want to rearrange this for your needs, but you should get the idea.

Comment: You don't really need `haveGetScaleFactorForMonitor`, you can simply check if `pGETSCALEFACTORFORMONITOR` is NULL or not

Comment: @RemyLebeau I simplified the code somewhat, thanks

Comment: Thanks that's worked for me. I just replace first line with typedef int `(*GetScaleFactor)(HMONITOR hMonitor, DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR *nScaleFactor);`